Expandable and collapsable rows in AngularJS
My main aim is to allow a user to expand a row with child rows when they click on button within a row. However everything seems correct from the data fetching side and the javascript side, but for some reason the rows do not appear when I click the button. I have no clue what else to do as I've been trying the whole of today to fix this.
I've tried everything I can think of and it all looks correct, I'm hoping you can guide me on what the issue could be.
This is my js:
$scope.toggleStockOrderDetails = function (index) {
    // Check if the index is within the bounds of the array
    if (index < 0 || index >= $scope.AgreementStockOrders.length) {
        console.error('Invalid index:', index);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Before toggle:', $scope.showDetails[index]);

    // Toggle the visibility of the details section
    $scope.showDetails[index] = !$scope.showDetails[index];

    // Check if the details for this item have not been fetched yet
    if (!$scope.AgreementStockOrders[index].stockOrderDetails) {
        // Create an empty stockOrderDetails array if it doesn't exist
        $scope.AgreementStockOrders[index].stockOrderDetails = [];

        // Call the GetStockOrderDetails function to fetch the details
        var productCode = $scope.AgreementStockOrders[index].ProductCode;
        AgreementsService.GetStockOrderDetails(productCode).then(function (response) {
            // Store the details in the corresponding item in AgreementStockOrders array
            $scope.AgreementStockOrders[index].stockOrderDetails = response.data;
        }, function (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching stock order details: ', error);
        });
    }

    console.log('After toggle:', $scope.showDetails[index]);
};

And the below is my html:
 <div has-permission="Agreement Detail Stock Order Detail">
     <h4>Stock Order Detail</h4>
     <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
             <!-- Table header -->
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th></th>
                     <th>Product code</th>
                     <th>Barcode</th>
                     <th>Description</th>
                     <th>PA Stock Required</th>
                     <th>DC SOH</th>
                     <th>Store SOH</th>
                     <th>Order Qty</th>
                     <th>Order Value</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <!-- Table body -->
             <tbody>
                 <!-- Loop through each item in AgreementStockOrders -->
                 <tr ng-repeat="item in AgreementStockOrders">
                     <!-- Toggle button to show/hide details -->
                     <td>
                         <button type="button" ng-click="toggleStockOrderDetails($index)">
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-large glyphicon glyphicon-expand"></i>
                         </button>
                     </td>
                     <!-- Display basic information -->
                     <td>{{ item.ProductCode }}</td>
                     <td>{{ item.Barcode }}</td>
                     <td>{{ item.Description }}</td>
                     <td>{{ item.PAStockRequired }}</td>
                     <td>{{ item.DcSoh }}</td>
                     <td>{{ item.StoreSoh }}</td>
                     <td>{{ item.OrderQty }}</td>
                     <td style="text-align: right">{{ item.OrderValue | number:2 }}</td>
                 </tr>
                 <!-- Details section -->
                 <tr ng-if="showDetails[$index]">
                     <td colspan="9">
                         <div>
                             <!-- Nested table to display details -->
                             <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-custom">
                                 <!-- Table header -->
                                 <thead>
                                     <tr>
                                         <th>Store code</th>
                                         <th>Store name</th>
                                         <th>PA Stock Required</th>
                                         <th>DC SOH</th>
                                         <th>Store SOH</th>
                                         <th>Weekly Mvmt</th>
                                         <th>Order Qty</th>
                                         <th>Order Value</th>
                                         <th>Comments</th>
                                     </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                 <!-- Table body -->
                                 <tbody>
                                     <!-- Loop through details of the selected item -->
                                     <tr ng-repeat="detail in AgreementStockOrders[$index].stockOrderDetails">
                                         <!-- Display details -->
                                         <td>{{ detail.StoreId }}</td>
                                         <td>{{ detail.StoreName }}</td>
                                         <td>{{ detail.PAStockRequired }}</td>
                                         <td>{{ detail.DcSoh }}</td>
                                         <td>{{ detail.StoreSoh }}</td>
                                         <td>{{ detail.RateOfSale }}</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.OrderQty" /></td>
                                         <td style="text-align: right">{{ detail.OrderValue | number:2 }}</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.Comments" /></td>
                                     </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                                 <!-- Table footer -->
                                 <tfoot>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td colspan="9">
                                             <div class="pull-right">
                                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateStock()">Save</button>
                                             </div>
                                         </td>
                                     </tr>
                                 </tfoot>
                             </table>
                         </div>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
             <!-- Table footer -->
             <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                     <td colspan="8" style="text-align: right">Total:</td>
                     <td style="text-align: right">{{ total}}</td>
                 </tr>
             </tfoot>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div>

